# Returned data from sql in getServerSideProps isnt being assigned to declared variable

Tags: sql, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to get data from an sql table in the getServerSideProps function, but can't assign the fetched data to a declared variable in the same function. This is my getServerSideProps function.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let decks = [];

  db.query(
    `SELECT * FROM decks WHERE user = '${context.params.userID}'`,
    async (err, res) => {
      if (!err) {
        decks = res;
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  );

  return { props: { decks } };
}
```

How can I assign the data to decks so that I can return it?

Comment: maybe you should start with a tutorial https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/node-js-mysql-select-from-query-examples/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't answer my question. Even after following the steps in the tutorial I end up with the same issue.

Comment: Where does `db.query` come from? Are you using a thrid-party library? If so, which one?

Comment: This issue is that `getServerSideProps` is returning before the `db.query` callback gets a chance to execute.

Comment: @juliomalves db is a connection I've made in a seperate file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use `mysql` or `mysql2` packages, and assuming you respect all next.js rules you could try:

1. remove `async` keyword on

```js
async (err, res) => {...}
```

, as it should be a normal function and console.log(res) what you get as a result; make sure db query is correct

2. You could try a promise based example
3. You could use an ORM, for example i use Prisma, it simplifies a lot database queries

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put

```
return { props: { decks } };
```

in if condition after:

```
decks = res;
```